# Сравнение значений в Binding MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как можно сравнить значение в биндинг?
У меня есть ListView с привязанной к ней ObservableCollection
в обьекте есть поле даты. При выводе коллекции в ListView мне надо сравнить дату с текущей(>, <, =) и в зависимости от результата окрасить строку в один из 3х цветов указанных в отдельном проперти

Comment: Триггер и конвертор

Comment: и..? я и сам догадался что это как-то связано, можно конкретику? как это реализовать чтобы работало

Comment: Я вам вроде максимально конкретно сказал, что и как, или вы хотите готовый код? Ну, это лично не в моих интересах давать вам готовое, ибо я хочу, чтоб вы научились, поняли сами, сами попробовали написать, ведь это ооочень просто. Вот что такое триггер? Это элемент стиля, который позволяет по конкретному условию (будь то свойство стиля, событие, свойство данных) сделать конкретные изменения в дизайне. Вот собственно и пишете `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="True">...</DataTrigger>`, где `SomeProperty` свойство для проверки, а `True` - его значение.

Comment: Спросите, но как сделать проверку с текущей датой, ведь `SomeProperty` - это просто дата объекта. А тут у вас 2 варианта. 1. Как я и сказал выше - конвертор, который возьмет дату, проверит и выдасть `True` или `False`. Как их написать - да в интернете полно примеров, думаю найдете очень быстро. 2. Это происать данную логику в самом классе (где свойство `SomeProperty`), и уже его в триггере и проверять. Ну а в самом триггере, просто задавайте через `Setter` нужному свойству дизайна, нужное значение. Вот собтственно и все...